# global scope not accessible inside of function?

Tags: javascript

Why does this code work?

```
function run(){
  var name =document.getElementById('name');
  name.classList.toggle('name');

}
```

But this code doesnt?  var name is defined in the global scope so why isnt it accessible in the run function?

```
var name =document.getElementById('name');
function run(){    
  name.classList.toggle('name');
}
```

Comment: It probably doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: `name` is also a native Global property of the `window` object and should always be avoided as an identifier name.

Comment: As for your main question, when is `run()` invoked and where is your code being placed within the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`run()` isn't being called until after the DOM is fully parsed, so when it attempts to execute:  `document.getElementById('name');`, the element will be found.

But, when that line is extracted from `run()` and placed outside of the function, it is being invoked prior to the DOM being fully parsed and the element is not found.

You can solve this by placing all of your code (or the `script` reference to your code), just before the closing `body` tag (`</body>`). By the time the browser encounters this, all of the HTML will have been parsed into memory and the element can be found.

```css
.name { background: red; color: white;  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="name" class="name" onclick="run()">Name</div>
  
  <!-- When the script is placed after all the other body content, it will
       be able to scan the DOM for any of that content. -->
  <script>
    var other =document.getElementById('name');
    function run(){
      other.classList.toggle('name');
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And, as I mentioned in my comment, it's best not to ever name anything `name` because `name` is a property of the Global `window` object and complications can arise when you use that identifier.

Comment: Notice: It will throw error if you use `name` instead of `other`.

Answer (score -1):

`name` is global property ie. window.name. Define the variable to something else:

```js
    var other =document.getElementById('name');
    function run(){
      other.classList.toggle('name');
    }
```

```css
.name {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div id="name" class="name" onclick="run()">Name</div>
```

It will work fine now.

---

Whilst, you use name, it will throw error:

```js
var name =document.getElementById('name');
    function run(){
      name.classList.toggle('name');
    }
```

```css
.name {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div id="name" class="name" onclick="run()">Name</div>
```

What's going on here?

You're modifying window property name with and html object. And you're using classList which is actually property of html object but not of window. So, accessing classList property on window property (though it's transformed to html object, it's still window object) will obviously throw you undefined error.

So, it's strongly discouraged to mutate the global property.

---

Inside the local scope, you're not modifying window property but defining local variable, so that works fine.

Comment: *It will work fine now.* Not if the first line of code is executing before the DOM is loaded. `name` being a Global property is important (and why I mentioned it in my comment), but it's not necessarily the issue here.

Comment: Actually, you are misreading the question and taking something that I pointed out as a general FYI and proposed that as the problem/solution.